# Using Gephi inside a Play Application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, gephi

I am currently building a Play Framework application in Scala that requires the use of the Gephi Java library.

I tried adding Gephi as a managed dependency in SBT, but SBT cannot resolve all of Gephi's dependencies. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit/issues/16). I then simply tried to add the whole Gephi JAR in my `lib/` folder as an unmanaged dependency. IntelliJ detects the library just fine and I can compile my application perfectly fine. The problem is an exception occurs immediately upon starting the application, and it seems to be related to dependency injection:

```
    play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:174)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.getKeyStrength(CacheBuilder.java:529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:242)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4718)
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:807)
    at com.google.inject.internal.WeakKeySet.<init>(WeakKeySet.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InheritingState.<init>(InheritingState.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.getState(InjectorShell.java:209)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.lock(InjectorShell.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
```

I tried removing all mention of Gephi in the code, while still having the JAR sitting in my `lib/` folder, but it results in the same exception.

Gephi is really important for this project, so I can't just move on to another library. Any ideas?

Comment: do `activator clean compile run`

Comment: I already tried that but unfortunately it didn't do any good :/

Comment: The problem is because of come cache that you are using .. see the complete stack trace

Comment: The problem also occurs if I use a minimal play app without referencing any part of Gephi in the code. Are there any sbt cache other than what's cleaned by "activator clean".

Comment: Remove Gephi code from `lib` also and then try to compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that jar fom `lib`, add those two additional resolvers (in `build.sbt`)

```
resolvers += "NetBeans" at "http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/"

resolvers += "gephi" at "https://raw.github.com/gephi/gephi/mvn-thirdparty-repo/"
```

and run `activator update`

Comment: Thanks, now the build works out okay, but for some reason I don't access to some classes for ``gephi-toolkit``. For example, ``org.gephi.graph.api.GraphController`` doesn't exist even though I can access other classes from the same package such as ``org.gephi.graph.api.Node``

Comment: Isn't that a problem in the IDE configuration (if you add an import of `org.gephi.graph.api.GraphController` and compile, it works?) ? If so it's probably best to ask another question, as that has not much to do with the original problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no it doesn't compile with the added import, even when I compile outside of IntelliJ using sbt in the CLI.

Comment: I opened [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733624/missing-classes-in-gephi-toolkit-after-sbt-build) to address my issue, and I'm closing this one since your answer was enough to solve the build problem. Thanks!